# android new activity with intent and textView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar

I am new to android and I am doing tutorial from developer.android. I am doing "Starting Another Activity" part. But my app is not working, I get "Unfortunately app has stopped working".
Here is the code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Proveravamo da li je verzija Androida Honeycomb ili veca da bi koristili ActionBar APIje
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        //Prikazi UP dugme u ActionBar
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent(); //Uzimamo intent koji je poslala MainActivity
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE); //Uzimamo EXTRA_MESSAGE iz intenta koji smo prihvatili

    //dodajemo textView
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Comment: Can you show error log?

Comment: Where you started your activity??

Comment: I get "no view found for id 0x7f05003c for fragmet PlaceholderFragment"

Comment: When i make TextView manualy in .xml file, and I set message from intent on it, it works. But when I try to make TextView through code, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was making trouble. It was this part of the code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    //Prikazi UP dugme u ActionBar
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Extras are retrieved on the other side via: [code edited]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key"); //if it's a string you stored.
```

[added] Don't forget to add your new activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

Comment: I did make new intent like that, and i did retrieve extras like that.
I am using Eclipse, so it adds new activity to manifest by itself.

Comment: No, you have to add your activities to manifest.. By default only main launching activity only added to manifest

Comment: If it wasn't added to manifest, it wouldn't be able to start second activity. I found what problem was.

Answer (score -1):

First a fall, what i can see from your code

```
you are trying to inflate TextView directly in setContentView() which is wrong , 
You have to inflate the complete layout file that represents your Activity layout like;

setContentView(R.layout.yourXML_filename);
```

Secondly,

```
You need to define setContentView() at the first in onCreate() not at the end, 
what i can see in this code.
```

Like.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.yourXML_filename); 

  .......Do your stuff what you are doing and wanna do
  .......

 }
```

And please let me know whether this resolves your issue or not....

Comment: It didn't resolve my issue. I did try it like that first, but i get same error.